# Imacros extract image src/url

Tags: javascript, url, extract, src, imacros

There is a thread about it, but i could not make it happen.
I should use eval but do not know how

```
tag pos=1 type=image attr=href:* extract=htm
```

set !extract eval("???")

After all the extract value should be an url.jpg

I will pick the answer with an example

Comment: This question makes very little sense ?

Comment: Start searching on stack. There are tons of JS solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iMacros Doesn't support to extract src directly from HTML element. For this, you have to extract html element and after that using javascript eval with regex you can easily get src or any other part of html element

If your hrml element is something similar like the below

```
<img id="imgFull" src="http://mysite/images/51cBAfufUrL.jpg" class="image-stretch-vertical frontImage" style="max-width:230px; max-height:346px;">
```

Then, you can simply get SRC with the following code with iMacros

```
TAG XPATH="//img[@id="imgFull"]" EXTRACT=HTM
SET SRC EVAL("\"{{!EXTRACT}}\".match(/src.*class/)[0].replace(/src=\"/,\"\").replace(/\"\\sclass/,\"\");")
SET !EXTRACT NULL
ADD !EXTRACT {{SRC}}
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=* FILE=SRC.csv
```